# How to find the induced measure?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I have the function $T:([0,1]^2,ℬ2)→(ℝ,ℬ)$ with $T((x_1,x_2)):=x_1−x_2$ and I want to calculate $λ_2T^{−1}$ with $λ_2T^{−1}(B):=λ_2(T^{−1}(B))$ for $B∈ℬ$.

I´ve already found out that $T^{-1}([a,b])=\{(x_1,x_2)\in[0,1]^2|a\leq x_1-x_2\leq b\}$ but I have problems calculating $\lambda_2(T^{-1}([a,b]))$.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\lambda_2 (\{(x,y): x-y \leq b\}=\int_0^{1-b} \int_0^{y+b}dxdy+\int_{1-b}^{1} \int_0^{1}dxdy$.